# Show that we have an induced quadratic form on quotient vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, quadratic-forms, bilinear-form

There is a quadratic form $q$ on a finite dimensional real vector space with associated symmetric bilinear form $\phi$. There is a subspace $R \leq V$ such that $\phi(r,v) = 0 \forall r \in R$ and $\forall v \in V$. I want to show that $q'(r+R) = q(r)$ defines a quadratic form on the quotient space $V/R$.

The reason why I'm struggling on this question is because I don't understand what this actually amounts to showing. What do I have to do? Can't we just restrict $\phi$ to $V/R$ and then the restriction of $\phi|_{V/R}$ to its diagonal is the quadratic form $q'$ on the quotient space? What do we actually have to do/show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't "restrict $\phi$ to $V/R$" because $V/R$ is not a subset of $V$.

What you need to show is that $q(v)  = q(v')$ for all $v, v' \in V$ such that $v + R = v' + R$; this is what is required for $q'$ to be well-defined. Once we know $q'$ actually exists then we check that it is a quadratic form, which is straightforward.

Put another way, given the canonical projection $\pi : V \to V/R$ you need to show that there exists $q' : V/R \to \mathbb R$ such that $q'\circ\pi = q$; this requires the specific properties of $R$. By linearity and surjectivity of $\pi$ it then follows that $q'$ is a quadratic form.

Comment: So we can say that $\phi(v_1 + r_1, v_2 + r_2) = \phi(v_1, v_2)$ for all $v_1, v_2 \in V, r_1, r_2 \in R$ implies $\phi$ will define a well-defined quotient bilinear form on $V/R$ which we can call "$\phi'$. Therefore the form $q'$ is the restriction of $\phi'$ to its diagonal and is therefore the quadratic form on the quotient space that we wanted?

Comment: @Featherball Yes, with $\phi'$ of course defined as $\phi'(v_1+R, v_2+R) = \phi(v_1,v_2)$. You also need to argue that this $\phi'$ is actually bilinear; this is straightforward, but you need to make sure you understand why.

Comment: excellent thank you